# How to use custom docker image for development via python session in terminal/console or jupyter in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

How to use custom docker image for development via python session in terminal/console or jupyter in AWS? I am able to run Jupyter notebook with preloaded environment in AWS, for example. However, if I want to install other packages, I'd like to maintain it in docker image and use the image to run something in sagemaker or ec2 or other compute services. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this out - https://herrmann.tech/en/blog/2021/02/08/how-to-build-custom-environment-for-jupyter-in-docker.html